# Access complete list for each index of for loop

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have 4 lists such as:

```
m1_jan = [2.3,3.2]
m1_feb = [3.2,2.3]
m2_jan = [1.2,1.7]
m2_feb = [4.5,6.7]
```

and I want to get minimum value of each list and tried following:

```
mon = ['jan','feb']
for i in xrange(1,3,1):
    for j in mon:
        l = 'm' + str(i) + '_' + j
        print l, min(l)
```

I get list names right but not getting correct minimum values and instead get following:

```
m1_jan 1
m1_feb 1
m2_jan 2
m2_feb 2
```

Any suggestions how to get minimum value of each list?

Comment: Can you store them as a list of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we change:

```
print l, min(l)
```

to:

```
print globals()[l], min(globals()[l])
```

The output will be as requested:

```
[2.3, 3.2] 2.3
[3.2, 2.3] 2.3
[1.2, 1.7] 1.2
[4.5, 6.7] 4.5
```

**Explanation:**
The variables that you're looking for are stored in the dictionary of [globals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)

That said, it's a better practice to store these variables in your own dictionary and access them through it, instead of relying on `globals()`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `dictionary`

```
d = {}
d['m1_jan'] = m1_jan
d['m1_feb'] = m1_feb
d['m2_feb'] = m2_feb
d['m2_jan'] = m2_jan

for mon, min_val in d.items():
    print("{} {}".format(mon, min(min_val)))
```

Output

```
m1_feb 2.3
m2_feb 4.5
m2_jan 1.2
m1_jan 2.3
```